# vue-clipboard2 not working inside bootstrap-vue modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue, clipboard.js

I have used the vue-clipboard2 plugin inside the bootstrp-vue modal. But the text is not copying.

Then I tried to copy to clipboard with vanilla js inside the bootstrap-vue modal. But the text is not copying.

Anyone can do figure out what's the problem??

Comment: Could you provide some sample code on how you are using both together?

Comment: just add this line `VueClipboard.config.autoSetContainer = true` before `Vue.use(VueClipboard)`

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me and uses the new [Clipboard API writeText method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) which is supported by most modern browsers (see [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_clipboard_writetext) for more details) and does not require vue-clipboard.

```js
//If you want to copyText from Element
function copyTextFromElement(elementID) {
  let element = document.getElementById(elementID); //select the element
  let elementText = element.textContent; //get the text content from the element
  copyText(elementText); //use the copyText function below
}

//If you only want to put some Text in the Clipboard just use this function
// and pass the string to copied as the argument.
function copyText(text) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
}
```

```html
<div id="mytext">This is some text that needs to be copied</div>
<button onclick="copyTextFromElement('mytext')">Copy</button>
```

Comment: omg, this is such a great answer! just use a function....

Comment: Thanks. I was probably lucky in being the first few people to use the api.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this specific problem is in the docs at https://github.com/Inndy/vue-clipboard2.

By using a container option:

```
let container = this.$refs.container
this.$copyText("Text to copy", container)
```

Or you can let vue-clipboard2 set container to current element by doing this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueClipboard from 'vue-clipboard2'

VueClipboard.config.autoSetContainer = true // add this line
Vue.use(VueClipboard)
```